# Getting Processes via Get-Counter does not refresh when processes change and throws errors if processes end

Tags: powershell

My script monitors the CPU usage of the process, looping the code every 5 sec and writing it to a file. Which works fine.

But I found when a new Process runs my script will not find it until I stop the script and rerun it again.

Also if a process ends/stops, the script give an this error:

> Get-Counter : The data in one of the performance counter samples is
>   not valid.   View the Status property for each
>   PerformanceCounterSample object to make sure it  contains valid data.
>
> At line:2 char:34

It seems PowerShell retrieves the Process information only once and caches it.

If I run the bellow script (which is a part of all my script), it runs perfectly:

```
while($true) {
     $ProcessId = (Get-Counter "\Process(*)\ID Process").CounterSamples
     $ProcessId.count
     Start-Sleep -s 5
}
```

If I have 50 process it will gives 50, but if a new process starts it will keep giving 50 until I restart the script.

If I stop any process it will give the same error above.

Any idea how to solve this problem and force PowerShell to reread the process list without restarting the script?

Comment: After the execution of each time,Restart it (Just a fix,may not be the best solution).Main(){Which Calls Main as the last step.}This may do the trick

Comment: By doing that you may start the execution of the complete script

Comment: How i can restart it from the code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use PowerShell Jobs to execute it in a new background process on each iteration and use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress the error messages that might occur if one or more processes stopped during a check:

```
while($true) {
    $ProcessId = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { (Get-Counter "\Process(*)\ID Process" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
    $ProcessId.Count
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Comment: This works greate. Now i have anther problem. I put my code in a ps1 file. And crested a task to run my code. The code works fine but it runs only one time. Then it keeps running but no output. If I stop the task and run it again it works again only once. If i run it from command it works fine. How i can trace the problem

Comment: Good news. I recommend you open a new question for your new problem as then it will get more visibility. If this answer has helped please consider marking it as accepted.